# "Unresolved reference: Pair" using Kotlin with Robolectric

Tags: android, kotlin, robolectric

## "Unresolved reference: Pair" using Kotlin with Robolectric

I tried adding Robolectric to a project that uses `android.util.Pair` so I can unit test the associated classes.  The project is in java, but the unit tests are all (so far) in Kotlin.

When I try to run the unit tests, I get the error:

```
:app:createMockableJar UP-TO-DATE
e: E:\...\TestK.kt: (3, 21): Unresolved reference: Pair
e: E:\...\TestK.kt: (12, 17): Unresolved reference: Pair
:app:compileDebugUnitTestKotlin FAILED
```

I created a simple test case:

```
import android.util.Pair
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class TestK {
    @org.junit.Test
    fun testk() {
        val p = Pair.create("Foo", "Bar")
        assertEquals("Foo", p.first)
        assertEquals("Bar", p.second)
    }
}
```

This produces the error, but if I create the same test in java, it works fine:

```
import android.util.Pair;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class Test
{
    @org.junit.Test
    public void test()
    {
        Pair<String, String> p = Pair.create("Foo", "Bar");
        assertEquals("Foo", p.first);
        assertEquals("Bar", p.second);
    }
}
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

my gradle file has the following deps:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: "kotlin-android"

... stuff ...

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.0.1"
```

And I'm using Kotlin 1.3

Comment: You can't use the Java Pair in Kotlin.

Comment: Why not? I thought you could use anything from Java.  The real (java) code that I'm trying to test has functions that return `Pair<>`.

Comment: Can your code resolve this line: `import android.util.Pair;`?

Comment: @Aaron it can in Java, but not in Kotlin, that's what I'm trying to figure out.  Robolectric is supposed to supply this class afaik.

Comment: I could be wrong but it might have something to do with your test gradle, do you have `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` or `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'`?

Comment: I have both: `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` and `apply plugin: "kotlin-android"`

Comment: Kotlin has its own Pair class, and for some reason it doesn't let you use the Java Pair class. An alternative would be to return the Kotlin Pair in the Java code, or just don't use Pair.

Comment: Actually, you should be able to use Pair. I'm not really sure why you can't. See if [this library](https://github.com/android/android-ktx) helps. It adds the extension methods `android.util.Pair#toKotlinPair()` and `kotlin.Pair#toAndroidPair()`.

Comment: Yea I don't understand why you can't, it's just a java class right?  I can copy the Pair.java file from android source and drop it into my project and everything works fine.  I think the problem is with Robolectric not supplying it's stub of `Pair`

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out to be the fact that I had an empty `Pair.java` file in my project at `android.util`.  It is where I had originally created a java stub for `Pair`, and when switching to Robolectric I commented everything in the file out.

While this seemed to be fine for java, apparently it wasn't enough for Kotlin, which was still trying to use that file I guess?  Anyway, after I deleted the empty file everything started compiling correctly!

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin we use UtilPair instead of Pair

just import like

```
    android.util.Pair as UtilPair
```

and then use it as

```
   val myPair = UtilPair.create<String?, String?>("Foo", "Bar")
```